# locate a div that covers the entire screen, how to make an element stand out?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to generate a screen that covers all my application. but I want the menu circle to stand out, that the user can interact with it while the rest of the application has a div with a class called **screen** that covers 100% of my screen.

```
<div class="screen"></div>
.screen{
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  opacity:0.9;
}
```

how can I do it?

[image]

I only get this:

[image]

I share the source code that I am doing, if you want to edit something, you must modify the **app/app.css** file(css) and **pages/home/home.ts** (.js), to see in real time.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-level-side-menu-waldmo?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Answer (score 1):

use z-index to make it go to top to 9999 level

```
z-index: 9999;
```

also position it

```
position: relative;
```

z-index the div covering the page with 99 and z-index the button with 100

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make something stand out the front, as in it's in front of the screen, then yes, you should use this CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="screen">        
  <div class="menu">
    <!--Stuff here-->
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>        
  .screen {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    opacity:0.9;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .menu {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
</style>
```

Please note that this is just how I would do it, you might have to modify it to suit you.